# In HTML/JavaScript how do I submit multiple posts from one button, leading a to a new page being opened on a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, http-post

How do I submit open multiple pages via a a post request from a single form/button

Currently I have a table with each row representing a song artist and a song and on each row there is an **Unlink** button that uses a form to submit a post action to a server which results in a new page being opened on a new tab, and this works fine

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://acoustid.org/edit/toggle-track-mbid" method="POST">
  <input name="state" value="1" hidden="">
  <input name="track_id" value="9509889" hidden="">
  <input name="mbid" value="6573f01d-0df5-442d-90c3-a69783c217c3" hidden="">
  <input type="submit" value="Unlink">
</form>
```

What I want to be able to do is also have a an *Unlink All by Artist* button that will find all rows with the same artist as the row clicked on and then submit a post request for each.

So I can find the rows okay using *getElementsByName()* , my difficulty is I don't understand only to submit multiple posts, with each post resulting a new page being opened in a new tab.

I'm assuming my JavaScript for the UnlinklllByArtist would find the required rows, and then for each row call another JavaScript function to submit the post but how do I do this second part.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Why open a new tab at all? Why no AJAX? And why a request for every artist and not one for all of them?

Comment: Ive reviewed various answers but none of them seem to fit the bill such as using ajax which wont work because doesnt link to frontend, using curl which is no good because needs to work from the webpage, not even sure it is possible.

Comment: Because on each page the user then has to click on a button, the acoustid.org site i connect to is not my site I dont have contorl over that site works, it opens a page for each artist/song that is how it works.

Comment: _"...such as using ajax which wont work because doesnt link to frontend"_ can you elaborate? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: As far as I know most modern browsers implemented a restriction merely allowing one action to open one window/tab.

Comment: @jabaa my understanding of ajax is it can asynchronusly submit a post to a server, but the reponse of the server will just come back to the async call, I dont want a reposnse to come back to the javascript I want the call to open a new page like the current form post does.

Comment: @Andreas Is it possible or not to do what i want to do, click on one button and end up sensing two post request to a server each ending up with a new tab being opened.

Comment: If it works with one tab, it will also work with multiple tabs... (if the browser doesn't stop you, which would be completely understandable)

Comment: You can trigger multiple button clicks / submits with one button click but my browsers won't allow a website to open multiple tabs.

Comment: @Andreas I dont see how do it

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/k8xr17Lp/1/) is an example snippet. But my browsers open the first tab and block all other tabs. I get a message, that tabs / popups were blocked. I have the option to allow this action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger multiple button clicks / submits with one button click, but my browsers initially won't allow a website to open multiple tabs. I get a message, that tabs / popups were blocked. I have the option to allow this action.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
  forms[0].submit();
  forms[1].submit();
});
```

```html
<form target="_blank" action="https://acoustid.org/edit/toggle-track-mbid" method="POST">
  <input name="state" value="1" hidden="">
  <input name="track_id" value="9509889" hidden="">
  <input name="mbid" value="6573f01d-0df5-442d-90c3-a69783c217c3" hidden="">
  <input type="submit" value="Unlink">
</form>
<form target="_blank" action="https://acoustid.org/edit/toggle-track-mbid" method="POST">
  <input name="state" value="1" hidden="">
  <input name="track_id" value="9509889" hidden="">
  <input name="mbid" value="6573f01d-0df5-442d-90c3-a69783c217c3" hidden="">
  <input type="submit" value="Unlink">
</form>
<button>
  Unlink All
</button>
```

Comment: ok, thanks I understand it, I was thinking I needed one form to submit to multiple actions but yo have done so code call multiple existing forms with each form just submitting to one page

Comment: Ive implemented a version of your answer, but had to add a 1 second delay between each form submit() (which is not ideal) so that all the submit workand with that it is working on Firefox, does that make sense. So basically means I only have to click one button to unlink all row for any artist, but if they have 20 rows I would then have to wait 20 seconds before i could continue to another artist. So this is a big improvement but not totally ideal.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Is this because of the built-in popup blocker?

Comment: i dont know that is why i am asking you

Comment: @PaulTaylor As I said, my browsers (Chrome and Firefox) initially only allow one popup at a time. If you can open multiple popups using a timeout, you found a workaround. Instead, you could allow multiple popups for one website in your browser, but that is a configuration only the visitors of your website can do.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I've tried this code: https://jsfiddle.net/9sk4861n/ Firefox and Chrome seem to block multiple popups, even with 5 seconds timeout. Firefox shows a message. Chrome silently blocks the popups. I'm not sure, how you've implemented the workaround, but it doesn't seem to work for my browsers.

Comment: im not opening a popup, Im opening in new tab, is that the difference, yo can see working at http://reports.albunack.net/new_acoustid_report1_1.html

Comment: @PaulTaylor Technically, there is no difference between a popup and a new tab. A popup is a new window. You can either add a new window as a tab to an already open window, or you can open a new window. Popup blockers will handle them the same. I don't know where to click to submit multiple forms. I tried different buttons and only one popup was opened, and it doesn't even completely load. It looks like an infinite loop.

Comment: is the problem with your fiddle that you are opening same page with exact same parameters in both cases ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor What browser, version and operating system are you using? You should assume that it won't work for some users, because browsers and popup blockers will block the popups.

Comment: or could it be that im not using "_blank" anymore but just reusing secondpage as i no longer have a need to actually use the page the servers opens

Comment: Im on Windows using Firefox 94.0.2 (latets version i think)

Comment: @PaulTaylor If you don't need to open the websites in new tabs, why don't you use an AJAX request? That would make things much simpler. It would also solve the problem with 1 second timeout.

Comment: Okay when originally asked question I needed to click on submit button on each page opened, but since then found out a way from by original form submission by adding an extra input field I can bypass that do it unlinks direclty from my page. I tried using the hidden iframe method so tabbed windowe not opened but that failed due to authentication method, and I havent worked out how to use ajax yet but ecpecting will also have authentication issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244599/do-i-need-to-authenicate-again-if-use-asynchonous-request-rather-than-form-to-su

Comment: @PaulTaylor But JavaScript has access to the authentication token / cookie and can send it with the AJAX request. Cookies will also be automatically added to AJAX requests.

Comment: Okay that probably is the way to go now, but Ive been battling with this all day and will have to do some reading to work out to convert to ajax. But I can understand why my current impl works for me but not you.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Did you allow popups for the domain reports.albunack.net? I didn't allow them.

Comment: Not conciously, unless i had done it previously, how do i check that

Comment: @PaulTaylor In Chrome you can click on `Not secure` in the top left and `Site settings`. There you can see `Popups: blocked`. In Firefox you can open about:preferences#privacy and see the list of exceptions.

Comment: So I wrote the ajax code and it says Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://acoustid.org/edit/toggle-track-mbid. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). As I dont have control over https://acoustid.org/edit/toggle-track-mbid i guess that means I cant use AJAX after all ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor You can use a reverse proxy to solve the problem.

Comment: link would be useful i dont know what you mean

Comment: @PaulTaylor https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: okay I think I will stick with what I have

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using **GreaseMonkey**

This find each form and then submit to same tab in turn with a delay between each submission

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     AlbunackSubmitBadAcoustidsLinksOnPage
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @include  http://reports.albunack.net/new_acoustid_report10_1.html
// ==/UserScript==
function delayedOpenLink(form)
{
    form.submit();  
}

function check()
{
  var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
  var i=1;
  for(form of forms)
  {
    setTimeout(delayedOpenLink, 5000 * i, form);
    i++;    
  }
}

if (confirm("SubmitAcoustIds") == true) 
{
  check();
}
```